# How to connect to SQL Server over internet using Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, network-programming

I have SQL Server Enterprise installed on my desktop behind a router. I have Visual Studio 2013 set up with SQL Server Data Tools addon installed on my laptop. When I'm on the same network, Visual Studio detects the SQL Server automatically and I can access and perform queries.

But when I'm away from home, I go to `Visual Studio` > `Server Explorer` > right-click `Data Connections` > `Add Connection`

When I type in routerIP and click `Test Connection` it gives me a

> Named Pipes Provider, Error 40: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

When I type in routerIP\ServerName(aka computer name) and then click `Test Connection` and it gives me an

> Error 26 Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

I have portforwarding enabled for port 1433 from my router to my server and I ran nmap from outside the network on that port and the SQL service is listening.

I'm using SQL Server Authentication with the 'sa' account which worked over the local network.

So my question is: Why am I getting those errors?

Would using a VPN service make things easier?

Is there an easier or more efficient way to do this?

*****UPDATE*****

I just changed some settings in the configuration manager and now I can't even connect over the same network.

Comment: Silly question, but are you using your External IP address, rather than your Internal IP?

Comment: I'm using the external IP.